# what are the steps need to follow in order to train deepspeech on Google colab?

Tags: mozilla-deepspeech

what are the steps (A - Z) we need to follow in order to train a model using Colab?
how to prepare our own data set in case if I need to fine-tune it for my voice/ our country’s accent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Mozilla DeepSpeech PlayBook](https://mozilla.github.io/deepspeech-playbook/) is an excellent starting point for your question. It is not specific to Google Colab, but provides guidance on both data preparation and training.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. hope it will help to get a  good start